# Excel open mdb temp table, but Access don't see it

Tags: excel, ms-access

Access can open only table data and queries, but i need to get large data (more then 2kk rows) from temp tables which can only opens in Excel.
[image: access]
[image: excel]
How can I export this temp tables (~TMPCLP298071, ~TMPCLP96981) from *.mdb file into *.xls(x) or *.csv?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
First i add data from table `Data` -> `Export from access` -> `Choose a file` -> `Choose a table` -> `OK`. Excel says that he can't add more then 1048576 rows, agree with it. See the last row Id (table column, not excel row number) and on the next sheet `Data` -> `Export from access` -> `Choose a file` -> `Choose a table` and then in the `Properties` on the tab `Definition` in the `Command text` field erase `~TMPCLP298071` and write something like this `SELECT * FROM ~TMPCLP298071 WHERE id > '160970578017779200000345460'` and last data from table exports to the next sheet.
Where `~TMPCLP298071` - table name, `id` - column name, `160970578017779200000345460` - last value on the previous sheet
[image]
Question is opened. Maybe anybody can give a better solution?